# count how many data in array and increment javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm new in stackoverflow:
Here is my issue, i would like to count how many tickets by month a user has and push it in my array,
i did that:

```
for(j=0; j< data.data.tickets.length ;j++){
   var requesterid = data.data.tickets[j].requester_id; 
   var created_at = data.data.tickets[j].created_at; 
   var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 7);
    if(created_at.includes(today)&& requesterid == cleartab[requesterid]['id']){total ++}     

      var arrayRef2 = cleartab[requesterid]['monthly'] || [];  
      cleartab[requesterid]['monthly'] = arrayRef2.concat([{"janvier":total}], [{"fevier":"fef"}]); 
}
```

The problem is that it gave me wrong result.

Here is my array:

[My array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqQ2w.png)

If my question is not clear, i can re-explain or tell me if you need something more to answer it

I hope you can help me
My issue:
Some people should not have ticket the result is not the good one. I would like to be sure that it increment only one people when 1 ticket has been sent in the current month. For now, when someone send a ticket in the current month, every user got +1 ticket in the current month. But what i want is that: it increment only for one user, the user who sent the ticket. Is that clear ?

Comment: What is "wrong" with the result?

Comment: Some people should not have ticket the result is not the good one. I would like to be sure that it increment only one people when 1 ticket has been sent in the current month. For now, when someone send a ticket in the current month, every user got +1 ticket in the current month. But what i want is that: it increment only for one user, the user who sent the ticket. Is that clear ?

Comment: Isn't that because you're using a global variable `total` which is shared by everyone? Have you tried making that a local variable?

Comment: Please don't post images of text (or JavaScript arrays in your case). Copy the text and post it as a code snippet. That way people can copy it and use it, and nothing is hidden as is the current case.

Comment: The variable total is something different what is interesting is my array "monthly"

Comment: It's "something different"? What do you mean? It's a global variable that you increment and never reset. Every time you enter the loop you increase its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the problem, you could try as below:

```
for(j=0; j< data.data.tickets.length ;j++){
    var requesterid = data.data.tickets[j].requester_id; 
    var created_at = data.data.tickets[j].created_at; 
    var today = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 7);
    // read the monthly for a given requestor or
    // initialize the new array by setting the total
    // to 0 "janvier:0
    var arrayRef2 = cleartab[requesterid]['monthly'] || 
                    [{"janvier":0}, {"fevier":"fef"}]; 

    if(created_at.includes(today) && 
       requesterid == cleartab[requesterid]['id']){
       // increment the total, very first time the value of
       //  arrayRef2[0].janvier will be zero, but in
       //  next iteration it will be always the previous value
       arrayRef2[0].janvier++;
     }     

     cleartab[requesterid]['monthly'] = arrayRef2; 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I just want to understand what you did, can you explain to me please :)

Comment: I have written the comments, basically whatever you have done the same but the total value is now being always taken from and incremented from cleartab[requesterid]['monthly'] so it will always be different for different users.